# Conflicting tags and how to deal with them

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

The [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) tag is defined as:

> This tag is for Microsoft Excel questions where the question or answers involve Excel formula, as opposed to VBA or other code mechanism.

The tag seems to be misused very frequently. In both of the following examples the OP is specifically asking for help with VBA code and looking for a VBA solution:

- [Macro to refresh an entire excel workbook(all data connections and calculations) every 15 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867158/macro-to-refresh-an-entire-excel-workbookall-data-connections-and-calculations)
- [How to copy only visible cells from workbook to workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36219806/how-to-copy-only-visible-cells-from-workbook-to-workbook)

This raises a few questions which I would like to put to the community:

- Can the [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) and [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tags ever be legitimately applied to the same question?
- If not, why is it that it is possible to assign both tags to a question? Surely a simple check could be applied prior to saving the question to ensure that tags which conflict with each other cannot be used?
- If it were agreed that conflicting tags should be prohibited, what mechanism could we use to ensure that conflicts are identified?
- Is a conflict check prior to save even the best solution or should be rely on the community to clean up these tags after the event?
- Given that we don’t currently have a ‘before-the-event’ solution, is it appropriate for a user to clean up these issues en masse?

Answer (score 1):

> Can the [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) and [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tags ever be legitimately applied to the same question?

I'd say so, for example if someone has a question about the `WorksheetFunction` object or the syntax of how to replicate a formula in VBA - some common errors in VBA might be:

```
'// Quotes not escaped in formula
Range("A1").Formula = "=IF(B1="test","true","false")"

'// Variable name used in literal string
Range("A1").Value = Application.Evaluate("=SUM(1,2,myVar)")

'// Regional delimiter used in VBA syntax
Range("A1").Formula = "IF(B1=""test"";""true"";""false"")"
```

All of which I would say are valid reasons to use the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) and [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) tag in conjunction.

***Real example:*** [Excel Inserting Formula with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584132/excel-inserting-formula-with-vba)

I think the tag wiki should maybe be amended to explain this a bit better though.

Comment: The phrase 'as opposed to' means 'rather than'/'instead of', it does not means 'as well as'. Does this mean that you think the definition of [tag: excel-formula] should be changed?

Comment: Just updated my answer with that very statement as you commented :)

Comment: I'll go with 'great minds think alike' rather than 'fools seldom differ'!

Comment: In fact, [I've just edited the tag wiki description](http://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/14948) so that will get peer-reviewed